# How to check data already added to Parse.com reentry of same data shouldn't be happenning how to do it

Tags: android, parse-platform

In Android Parse.com
If data with the same username is already added reentering of all the same data should be avoided
How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, first do a query and fetch the username before you try to save. If the query returned empty, then you know that username does not exist, and now you can push the new data.

If you use the parse user table, then you won't have to do this check. Parse will automatically check for you when you try to push an existing username.

Comment: How about other table?

Comment: Not User Table Suppose we are building add friends Table. The Table Already added friends name should not be added once again.

Comment: Bcoz in Parse User Table this functionality is present by default

Comment: Yes, on any table. Just query that table to see if entry already exists. If the entry does not exist, you will get back an empty array.

Comment: Ya, but tried in other way check for the list length to be great than zero else add to the table. Same way as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  It checks to see if username already exists:

```
public void register(final View v){
if(mUsernameField.getText().length() == 0 || mPasswordField.getText().length() == 0)
    return;

v.setEnabled(false);
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
user.setUsername(mUsernameField.getText().toString());
user.setPassword(mPasswordField.getText().toString());
//mErrorField.setText("");

user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoggedIn.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
            // to figure out what went wrong
            switch(e.getCode()){
                case ParseException.USERNAME_TAKEN:
                    mErrorField.setText("Sorry, this username has already been taken.");
                    break;
                case ParseException.USERNAME_MISSING:
                    mErrorField.setText("Sorry, you must supply a username to register.");
                    break;
                case ParseException.PASSWORD_MISSING:
                    mErrorField.setText("Sorry, you must supply a password to register.");
                    break;
                default:
                    mErrorField.setText(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            v.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
});
```

}